# relation "" does not exist in django for app name with mixed-case

Tags: django, postgresql, model

I have faced a problem while working with django models. lets say my apps name is `GasNet` and my models name is `Riser` well the generated table name is `GasNet.riser`, I can successfully generate table and add objects to table and even delete all of the objects of a table. But when I try to delete an object I face this error

```
The above exception (relation "GasNet_riser" does not exist LINE 1: ..."."createDateTime", "GasNet_riser"."deleted" FROM "GasNet_ri... ^ ) was the direct cause of the following exception:
```

in debug window the sql query is as

```
sql 
('SELECT "GasNet_riser"."id", "GasNet_riser"."city_code", '
 '"GasNet_riser"."geom"::bytea, "GasNet_riser"."node_code", '
 '"GasNet_riser"."pipe", "GasNet_riser"."parcel_code", '
 '"GasNet_riser"."Number", "GasNet_riser"."hack", "GasNet_riser"."multi_code", '
 '"GasNet_riser"."gis_code", "GasNet_riser"."angle", "GasNet_riser"."size", '
 '"GasNet_riser"."direction", "GasNet_riser"."instalation_date", '
 '"GasNet_riser"."description", "GasNet_riser"."type", '
 '"GasNet_riser"."status", "GasNet_riser"."instalation_type", '
 '"GasNet_riser"."material", "GasNet_riser"."zone_id", '
 '"GasNet_riser"."prejenti_id", "GasNet_riser"."emergency_sub_zone_id", '
 '"GasNet_riser"."updateDateTime", "GasNet_riser"."createDateTime", '
 '"GasNet_riser"."deleted" FROM "GasNet_riser" WHERE "GasNet_riser"."id" = %s')
```

this is my model

```
class Riser(models.Model):
    id=models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    city_code = models.CharField(max_length=10)

    geom = models.PointField(srid=4326)

    node_code = models.IntegerField(default=-1,blank=True)    # شماره گره جهت اعمال مصرف آن برروی گره در طراحی
    pipe = models.IntegerField(default=-1,blank=True)
    parcel_code = models.IntegerField(default=-1,blank=True)

    Number = models.CharField(max_length=20)  #کد علمک
    hack = models.IntegerField(default=-1,blank=True)
    multi_code = models.CharField(max_length=10,blank=True)
    gis_code = models.CharField(max_length=20,blank=True)

    angle = models.FloatField(default=-1,blank=True)
    size = models.IntegerField(default=-1,blank=True)
    direction = models.TextField(max_length=500,blank=True)


    instalation_date = models.DateField(null=True,blank=True) # تاریخ نصب
    description = models.TextField(blank=True)

    type = models.CharField(max_length=20,blank=True)     # همان فیلد kind هست

    # choises
    status = models.CharField(max_length=5,default=ModelChoiseFields.NAN, choices=ModelChoiseFields.RISER_STATUS,blank=True)
    instalation_type = models.CharField(max_length=5,default=ModelChoiseFields.NAN, choices=ModelChoiseFields.RISER_INSTALATION_TYPE,blank=True)
    material = models.CharField(max_length=5,default=ModelChoiseFields.NAN, choices=ModelChoiseFields.RISER_MATERIAL,blank=True)

    # relations
    zone = models.ForeignKey(Zone,on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=True)
    prejenti = models.ForeignKey(pt,models.CASCADE,null=True,blank=True)
    emergency_sub_zone = models.ForeignKey(EmergencySubZone,models.CASCADE,null=True)     # زیرناحیه امداد




    # Auto fields
    updateDateTime = models.DateTimeField('update date', auto_now_add=True, auto_now=False)
    createDateTime = models.DateTimeField('create date',auto_now_add=False, auto_now=True)
    deleted = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

I tried `makemigrations` and `migrate` and I know that table is fine but I have no idea why this happens.

I try to delete object using this method.

```
 selected=Riser.objects.get(id=id)
                selected.delete()
```

I think the problem is with app name and upper case `G` and `N` but I do not know how to fix this problem.

---

I also tried to delete using filter and the same error happens. it says

```
relation "GasNet_riser" does not exist LINE 1: DELETE FROM "GasNet_riser" WHERE "GasNet_riser"."id" = 1115 ^
```

when I run the above query manually in my database it runse with no problem `DELETE FROM "GasNet_riser" WHERE "GasNet_riser"."id" = 1115` returns `Query returned successfully: one row affected, 62 msec execution time.`

Comment: Django will look at your [app config](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/applications/#for-application-authors) for the applications name. If you don't have an app config, then Django will look at the directory name. If the app name is `GasNet`, then Django will use the prefix `GasNet_` for the tables in the app.

Comment: @Alasdair so if I only change app name in app config it will be fixed?there is not any thing to change?

Comment: I can't tell what the problem is from your question. You seem to think that the problem is the upper case `G` and `N`, so I explained where Django is getting them from. The full traceback might show what the problem is.

Comment: for me it was a problem with the table name, I had to specify the `db_table` in model's `Meta` to get it working